# Xcode how to save map annotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am new to mapkit and I figured out how to create map pins but there is absolutely no tutorial in cyberspace about how to save map annotation pins in Xcode. Do any of you know how I can do this. Is i core data? is it NSuserdefaults?

I am using Parse to store the longitude and latitude of a map pin, but I can only retrieve one coordinate at a time. 
Do any of you have any suggestions where I can pull down multiple annotation pins. How can I save multiple annotation pins and load them on the map??? Please help me.

```
PFQuery *que = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"map"];
    [que orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    que.limit=10;


    [que getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"lati"]);
            goat.text=[object objectForKey:@"lati"];
            goat2.text=[object objectForKey:@"longi"];


            NSString *ps;
            NSString *ls;
            ps=goat.text;
            ls=goat2.text;
            // int value = [ps intValue];
            //int valu = [ls intValue];
            NSLog(@"GOO %@", ps);
            NSLog(@"GOO %@", ls);
            lat=[ps floatValue];
            lon =[ls floatValue];






            NSMutableArray *locationss=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D dizhi;

            VP *myann;
            myann=[[VP alloc]init];


            dizhi.latitude =lat;
            dizhi.longitude =lon;


            myann.coordinate=dizhi;
            myann.title =@"arsenal";
            [locationss addObject:myann];

            NSLog(@"QAD %f", dizhi.latitude);
            NSLog(@"QAD %f", dizhi.longitude);

            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = myann.coordinate;
            point.title = @"Where am I?";
            point.subtitle = addre.text;

            [mapview addAnnotation:point];


                               myann=[[VP alloc]init];
                                dizhi.latitude =lattude;
                                dizhi.longitude =longtude;

                               myann.coordinate=dizhi;
                               myann.title =@"gees";
                                [locationss addObject:myann];

                               [mapview addAnnotations:locationss];


        }
    }];
```

Comment: Why are you setting the limit to 10 and then calling `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`? Ho do you prefer to save them? Does your app already use Core Data? Have you tried saving them somewhere?

Comment: I tried using "find object in backgorundwith block" but i cant retrieve any objects. I don't know how to convert a nsarray to a nsstring. I am not using core data. I am using parse. Do you how I can pull down more objects. I am using a viewcontroller and not a table view so I cannot use "load in background". Your thoughts??

Comment: You don't convert and array to a string, you iterate over it and process each item. You seem confused about different concepts, the same approaches apply wether you use a table view or not. Parse will also store the data locally for you anyway... I think you should read more about the parse supplied API.

Comment: Your comment is not that helpful, do you have some sample code or something I can use. I agree that the obvious answer to my problem is if I can pull down more coordinates from my database, but I don't know what parse method to call. I read their API and it is not helpful. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: You seem to be struggling with the more basic concepts like queries etc, I would strongly suggest you get more comfortable with those concepts before adding in complexity like location data. The queries will be pretty much the same with or without location information, it's all just data in the end. There are many free tutorials online to help you learn more about writing queries and displaying the results in a table.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can save and load one CLLocationCoordinate2D to NSUserDefaults.

```
// Save
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord = ...
NSData *coordinateData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myCoord length:sizeof(myCoord)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:coordinateData forKey:@"MyCoordinate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Load
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoord;
NSData *coordinateData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyCoordinate"];
[coordinateData getBytes:&myCoord length:sizeof(myCoord)];
```

Comment: Hi Filip, Thank you for the code, but the load part does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Call `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` and it will return the array of (up to) 10 location objects for you to iterate over.

Look also at `cachePolicy` which you could use to have parse SDK store the data for you, then you don't need to worry about Core Data or `NSUserDefaults`.